# I want to put my sliding div behind the main menu bar

Tags: html, css

I want my mega menu to be like this website https://www.storyblocks.com/stock-image. I have made the working almost like this one but I am not able to put the div behind the main menu. If I use the z-index I get the result but then when I move my cursor away from the main link it disappears.

I have tried changing the z-index, and I don't know how else can I achieve the same result.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.main-div ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.main-div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-div ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.main-div ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}

.sub-menu {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  z-index: -1;
  /* z-index: -1;<<<this is where I am stuck and don't know what to do*/
}

.main-div ul li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    margin-top: -300px;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="main-div">
        <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                  <!-- content -->
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Polos</a>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                  <!-- content -->
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Bags</a>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                  <!-- content -->
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Graphics</a>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                  <!-- content -->
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Other Stuff</a>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                  <!-- content -->
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: As per your code right now, with the `z-index` included, the `sub-menu` appears when you hover over a link, and stays if you move from that link to the `sub-menu`. The only time it disappears is when you hover away from the link to somewhere else. The website you sent has a similar functionality, then what is missing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. If you change the color of the .sub-menu div to red and hover over the link. You will see that the div slides from the top covering the menu text eg T-Shirt. So I want it to go behind the grey colored Un order list block. So by removing the /*comment*/ from z-index of .sub-menu I get the result but after that I won't stay when cursor goes away from the text block of main menu.

Comment: Also try to move your cursor to the .sub-menu div

Comment: save it as an html file and open it in chrome it won't work there.